# How to calculate the difference in months between two dates MONGODB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have to calculate the diference between two dates in months using Mongo's aggregate framework. The date is stored inside my DB in string format `2018-07-16 04:40:39` and i am getting the current date using `$date_test = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime('today') * 1000);` and then i subtract the values , but i am not getting the right result.

Below is my code that have tried so far

```js
The date is stored as '2018-07-16 04:40:39' in the collection
```

```js
$date_test = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime('today') * 1000);


'testt'=>
  [
    '$subtract'=>
      [
        [
          '$dateFromString'=> 
            [
              'dateString'=> '$timestamp','timezone'=> "America/New_York"
            ]
        ], 
      $date_test
   ]
 ]
```

Comment: Output you getting is a `timestamp`. You need to further divide it with `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30` to convert it to months.